# Transfering file from php upload to java using php-java-bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am trying to upload a file using php and transfer it to the java using php-javabridge. I don't know where to start? All i have is the

```
$FILES['tmp_name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with php-java-bridge, however you could do this:

- Sanitise the input
- Use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to call the java program passing the filename as a parameter